# How to Build an api to follow and unfollow user in laravel with postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman

How to create an Api in laravel to follow and unfollow user

```
public function follow(){
    $id = Auth::id();
    $result = User::where('id', '!=', $id)->get();
    //return $result;
    return response()->json(['data' => $result], 200,[],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}

public function followUser(user $user){
    if (!Auth::user()->isFollowing($user_id)){
        Auth::user()->follows()->create([
          'target_id' =>$user_id,
        ]);

        return response()->json(['sucess'=>'sucessfully followed']);
     }else{
        return response()->json(['oops'=>'u already followed ']);
     }
}

public function unfollowUser(User $user)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isFollowing($user->id)) {
        $follow = Auth::user()->follows()->where('target_id', $user->id)->first();
        $follow->delete();

        return response()->json(['success', 'You are no longer friends with '. $user->name]);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error', 'You are not following this person']);
    }
}
```

here is my code  and this is my route to use in postman

```
Route::post('/followUser/{user}','Api\FollowuserController@followUser');
Route::get('/unfollowUser/{user}','Api\FollowuserController@unfollowUser');
```

i am using the route to follow with sessionid on user id but getting nothing ...
how should i do this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you for route

```
Route::post('users/{id}/action', 'API\UserController@action');
```

and for body request:

```
{
  "act":"follow"   //or unfollow
}
```

table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('action_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('object_id')->unsigned();
        $table->enum('object_type',['USER','PAGE','POST']);
        $table->enum('act',['FOLLOW','UNFOLLOW','VISIT' ,'LIKE','DISLIKE']);
        $table->timestamp('created_at');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('restrict')
            ->onUpdate('restrict');
    });

   //Or to make it easier 
    Schema::create('follower_following', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('following_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(array('follower_id', 'following_id'));

        $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('restrict')
            ->onUpdate('restrict');

        $table->foreign('following_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('restrict')
            ->onUpdate('restrict');
    });
```

in model (user.php)

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower_following', 'following_id', 'follower_id')
        ->select('id', 'username', 'name','uid');
}


public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower_following', 'follower_id', 'following_id')
        ->select('id', 'username', 'name','uid');
}
```

action method: (if you have page and other object ... It's better to have this method in an trait)

```
  public function action($id, Request $request)
{

    // $user 




    switch ($request->get('act')) {
        case "follow":
            $user->following()->attach($id);
            //response {"status":true}
            break;
        case "unfollow":
            $user->following()->detach($id);
            //response {"status":true}
            break;
        default:
            //response {"status":false, "error" : ['wrong act']}
    }


}
```

Comment: how to show post of following user with all post        $user = User::with('followers.posts')->find(1); $user ->posts()just returning all following user post not all uploaded in db